# error: invalid user defined conversion from char to const key_type&

Tags: c++, string, c++11, dictionary, compiler-errors

I am trying to assign `int` type value to each letter in latin alphabet using `std::map`. When I want to create new int and give it a value equal to `int` mapped to word, i get an error:

> F:\Programming\korki\BRUDNOPIS\main.cpp|14|error: invalid user-defined conversion from 'char' to 'const key_type& {aka const std::basic_string&}' [-fpermissive]|

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::map <std::string,int> map;
    map["A"] = 1;
    int x;
    std:: string word = "AAAAAA";
    x = map[word[3]];

    cout << x;

    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @juanchopanza - you're right; but... was my answer was so trivial... Deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to assign int type value to each letter in latin alphabet using std::map.

So you have to use `char` (instead of `std::string`) as key of the map; something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<char, int>  map;
    map['A'] = 1;
    int x;
    std:: string word = "AAAAAA";
    x = map[word[3]];

    std::cout << x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As observed by others, now you're trying to use a `char` as a key for a `std::map` where the key is a `std::string`. And there isn't an automatic conversion from `char` to `std::string`.

Little Off Topic suggestion: avoid to give a variable the same name of a type, like your `std::map` that you've named `map`. It's legit but confusion prone.

Answer (score 1):

`word[3]` is of type `char`, and your map has a key of type `std::string`. There is no conversion from `char` to `std::string`.

Just take the substring of the string (by using [`string::substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)), by changing this:

```
x = map[word[3]];
```

to this:

```
x = map[word.substr(3, 1)];
```

---

Or better yet, use `char` as your key, since you need letters, like this:

```
std::map <char, int> map;
map['A'] = 1;
// rest of the code as in your question
```

Answer (score 0):

`word[3]` is a character at the fourth position of the string.  But you can't use that as a key for the map because the map uses a string as it's key.  If you change the map to have a key of char then it will work or you can:

- create a string from the word[3]
- use substr(3,1) to get the key